# After the turning of four dials, you are lost

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

While everything you've ever known is coming to an end, you go on A Long Walk because you think that you're Better Off Alone. You skipped your Night Shift just for this walk. Out on your walk, you see some Bloodflowers and a Butterfly near a Farmhouse. While you're Amazed, four invisible dials turn, and you're suddenly somewhere new, but it Doesn't Really Matter. You're not lost, and you're still Awake and Breathing. Though, with Everything In Its Right Place, something fundamental has changed. There's no one there to Hold Out Your Hand, but you must figure out where you are.

Where are you?

Comment: is the "bad" spelling intentional?

Comment: @Jasen After editing it to make it easier, I did notice one mistake, which has been corrected. My apologies. Any other mistakes left are intentional.

Comment: yeah, you found what i saw. I didn't want to mention it explicitly and spoil the puzzle for others.

Comment: So the apostrophe in "It's" is deliberate?

Comment: I don’t know whether to congratulate you for finding a dozen “famous” songs that I’ve never heard of, or to curse you for illuminating my cultural ignorance.  (Although, [“Amazed”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazed) was released in 1999, and a Google search for `"night shift" song 2000` gets no good results.)  So, instead, I’ll ask you why you left the erroneous apostrophe alone, even after it had been pointed out to you.  And why you didn’t capitalize the “m” in “matter”.

Comment: @PeregrineRook The songs were not songs strictly released in 2000. They are songs that had significant radio time or were high on the charts in 2000. The M is an honest mistake and I didn't see the comment pointing out the apostrophe until just now. Honest minor mistakes.

Comment: From the accepted answer, is the *question* really accurate? **Where** are you ? The answer doesn't answer that, does it? I understand that a question of "When" would spoil the puzzle - as would a [tag:music] tag, but somehow I feel a bit of narrowing/framing the puzzle could have improved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am I

> In the year 2000? Four invisible dials are the numbers of the year that all change from 1999 to 2000. All these songs are from 2000 (couldn't find Hold out your hand, but who knows). Everything coming to an end, etc refers to the end of the millennium.

Comment: A Google search for `Hold Out Your Hand song 2000` finds [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_State_(album) "*The State* (album) by Nickelback") and many similar results.

Answer (score 2):

> in a theatre?  the dial control the lights, sound, curtain, etc...

Comment: Nope, good guess though.

Answer (score 2):

Well, all the capitalized phrases are

> famous songs

But I'm not sure how they relate. Perhaps the answer has something to do with music.

The band names don't spell out anything either, unless I messed that up.

Comment: somewhere with recorded songs, and dials presumably... a radio station?

Comment: @Jasen I've edited the riddle to add one word, which should help a lot.

Comment: *Invisible* dials (anyone can view the edit history) , a dial is a face, and a face is for seeing.... interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Answer (well, guess):

> I think you are at the end of a radio dial.  Turning the dial you hear fragments of different songs.

Comment: Very interesting guess, but not correct. I will give you a hint, the dials have nothing to do with a radio station or the songs directly.

Answer (score 0):

I am in...

> `hELL`, because in digits, upside down, it would read like `1134` (or `7734`, depending on the font), which was dialed. [image]